# How can I incorporate audio in a website using HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio

I have been asked to produce a microsite for a client and they want it to be a presentation style website that will include audio narration.

They asked for it to be done in HTML5, but I haven't produced anything in HTML5 yet. Also they want it to reach a wide audience, so would HTML5 be applicable, what are the minimum browser requirements?

Other than Flash is there a way of producing voiceover for pages... jQuery maybe or anything else?

Would the options be

- HTML5 with limited browser support
- Flash based website which can't be viewed on an iPad/Phone
- No narration!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6426368/best-way-to-embed-background-music-in-a-webpage

Answer (score 4):

Any time you're developing with HTML5, you should consider ways to offer backward compatibility.

To determine minimum browser requirements, please visit here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_(HTML5)

Using HTML5 Audio:
http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_audio.asp

For HTML5 Audio, you will need at least two copies of the sound file to hit every browser: I would say one in mp3 format, the other in Ogg Vorbis.

You can use a simple browser detection javascript to determine browser and serve content accordingly: http://javascript.about.com/library/blbrsdet.htm

Generally, best practice would be to determine support, then fall back in order:

1. If they support HTML5, use `<audio>`
2. If they don't support HTML5, test for flash support. If ok, serve flash audio.
3. If neither, display a block of text with the content of the narration.

Essentially, always serve the latest and greatest, but support the technologies that got you there in the first place.

Comment: If I recall correctly, you don't even need to use Javascript for feature detection - at least for serving flash instead - wouldn't you simply add the tags for said player after the HTML5 content tags?

Comment: I believe that would result in double playing, but there may well be a way to do that I'm not aware of. You could perhaps (since much of HTML5 support relies heavily on javascript in various ways) replace the inner html of the block containing the Flash script with the HTML5 content in the event that javascript is functioning.

Comment: You should make the text of the narration available anyway.  Some people have sound turned off or are hearing impaired, or will be using a screenreader anyway.  Just make the text more obvious when the audio doesn't load.

Comment: This is true, and something to be considered. Personally I like hidden text that can be shown when clicked, but that's just me.

Comment: @stslavik: [No? I'm pretty sure it can be done.](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/audio/quick/#toc-player-custom/player_mp3_mini.swf)

Comment: @Nightfirecat: Good to know. As I said above "there may well be a way to do that I'm not aware of." Glad we could clear that up.

Answer (score 0):

This code should be highly compatible (IE6+), using WAVE:

```
<![if (!IE)|(gte IE 9)]>
<audio id="speak" src="speak_a.wav" type="audio/wav"></audio>
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('speak').play()">Speak</a>
<![endif]>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<bgsound id="speak" name="speak" autostart="false" loop="1">
<a href="#" onclick="document.all['speak'].src='speak_a.wav'">Speak</a>
<![endif]-->
```

Another option, using both mp3/ogg and still very compatible:

```
<![if (!IE)|(gte IE 9)]>
<audio id="speak">
  <source src="speak_a.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
  <source src="speak_a.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
  <a href="speak_a.mp3">Download speak_a.mp3 if you cannot play it</a>
</audio>
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('speak').play()">Speak</a>
<![endif]>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<bgsound id="speak" name="speak" autostart="false" loop="1">
<a href="#" onclick="document.all['speak'].src='speak_a.mp3'">Speak</a>
<![endif]-->
```

If you don't need to support IE9 and earlier, the `<audio>` tag should be enough:

```
<audio id="speak">
  <source src="speak_a.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
  <source src="speak_a.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('speak').play()">Speak</a>
```

Another old way of playing audio:

```
<object data="speak_a.wav" type="audio/wav">
  <embed src="speak_a.wav"></embed>
</object>
```

And you could also use third-party libraries such as [audio.js](http://kolber.github.com/audiojs/)