# Autoplaying music on website with out getting any permissions.

Tags: javascript, iframe, embed, playback

I would like to auto play a music in the background of my error 404 page. However I need it to sync up to a little animation. I've used the

```
<embed>
```

tag. However it asks for the permission to run quicktime. By the time the user would accept it, the animation would be over.
I've also tried autoplaying a youtube video, but it usually takes 3-5 seconds to buffer depending on one's internet connection. This is too long. Is there any solution to auto play a song with out any permissions?

Comment: Flash? Some horrible ads sometimes start playing some audio without asking and those ads are flash ads. You also have the HTML5 `<audio>` tag but that by itself would not be synced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `<audio>` tag, this will work on most browsers:

```
<![if (!IE)|(gte IE 9)]>
<audio id="speak" autoplay>
  <source src="speak_a.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
  <source src="speak_a.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
</audio>
<![endif]>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<bgsound id="speak" name="speak" autostart="true" loop="1">
<script>document.all['speak'].src='speak_a.mp3'</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Also see my other related answer in [How can I incorporate audio in a website using HTML5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326778/how-can-i-incorporate-audio-in-a-website-using-html5/14469838)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you could do it without flash using 100% HTML5 depending on your requirements (what browser support you need). That will

Here's a nice example: http://hungry-media.com/code/html5-audio-sync/

(Related to this blog post: http://hungry-media.com/2010/09/synchronizing-audio-with-html5/)